# Posting on facebook page - i am the only one who sees the post

Tags: facebook, post, visible

I searched all web long for this problem but nothing seems to fix it.

I am simply writing a post to a facebook page, the post is visibile on the page but only by myself and no from other admins or users.

How can it be possible?

I am using this function (also i'm pretty sure that the whole code is working as the post is on the page!):

$postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );

First i was guessing that was a privacy problem, but the page doesn't have that kind of parameter.

Whole code is:

`post_url = '/'.$page_id.'/feed';`

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");

//die(print_r($page_info));
//posts message on page statues 
$msg_body = array(
'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],

'message' => "test"
);

if ($fbuser) {
  try {
        $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

@------------@ EDIT @------------@

I still have the same problem, also, i checked a feed "manually" posted and a feed from my script, and the fields are exactly the same... that's insane.

@------------@ EDIT II: @------------@

I tried with a curl, nothing seems to work :/

Comment: Have you set the Visibility of the app and posts to "only me" ?

Comment: Are you posting as a user or as page?

Comment: Is the app in 'sandbox' mode? As set in the app settings on https://developers.facebook.com/apps ...

Comment: @Malcom, nope, if I set the Visibility field in the message array facebook gives me back an error like: "you cannot set visibility for page messages".

CBroe as a page.

James yes it is, as i'm testing from localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem has been solved.

As an idiot,  SandBox mode was activated (i didn't know that eveything done by the app was binded by the SandBox).

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of page access token to do that. 
Also, what `$post_url`, stands for? We can't guess from the code you wrote. Anyhow, you post either with `$pageid/feed` or with `me/feed` (and an access token). It should be something like `$facebook->api( '/me/feed/', 'post', array('access_token' => $page_access_token, 'message' => 'Test message', 'link' => 'http://somelink.com') );`

Comment: okay as far as I can see you might have problems with retrieving your page access token (different from your own access token), which you get with a graph query at `me/accounts `. That will return an array with all your pages. Something like this `{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "page category", 
      "name": "page name", 
      "access_token": "your page acces token", //you need this  
      "id": "page id numer", //you need this too
      "perms": [
        etc etc
        
      ]
    }`. try with a graph api explorer test? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Tried this way, didn't work. I also edited the first post, check it please :)